# Вывести данные из формы JS

Tags: javascript, html

Суть такова: в человек вводит данные 1, 2, 3, ф потом мы это выводим на странице html. Проблема в том, что я не могу вывести данные, так как они почти сразу пропадают.

Вот JS-код:

```
function say_hi() {
  var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
  var c = document.getElementById('c').value;
  var d = document.getElementById('d').value;
  var e = document.getElementById('e').value;
  var f = document.getElementById('f').value;
  var g = document.getElementById('g').value;
  var h = document.getElementById('h').value;
  var i = document.getElementById('i').value;
  var j = document.getElementById('j').value;
  var k = document.getElementById('k').value;

  var html = 'Hello <b>' + a + '</b> ' + b;

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
}
document.getElementById('slap').addEventListener('click', say_hi);
```

Вот HTML-код:

```
<form class="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="a" class="form-control" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="b" class="form-control" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="c" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="d" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="e" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="f" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="g" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="h" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="i" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="j" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="k" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
                 <div class="row">
                <hr>
                  <div id="result"></div>
                <hr>
              </div>
              <button id="slap" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Рассчитать</button>
            </form>
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function say_hi(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
  var c = document.getElementById('c').value;
  var d = document.getElementById('d').value;
  var e = document.getElementById('e').value;
  var f = document.getElementById('f').value;
  var g = document.getElementById('g').value;
  var h = document.getElementById('h').value;
  var i = document.getElementById('i').value;
  var j = document.getElementById('j').value;
  var k = document.getElementById('k').value;

  var html = 'Hello <b>' + a + '</b> ' + b;

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
}
document.getElementById('f1').addEventListener('submit', say_hi);
```

```html
<form id="f1" class="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="a" class="form-control" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="b" class="form-control" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="c" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="d" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="e" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="f" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="g" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="h" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="i" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="j" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Текст</label>
                <input id="k" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Текст">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
                 <div class="row">
                <hr>
                  <div id="result"></div>
                <hr>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Рассчитать</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function say_hi(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="slap" type="button" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

перенести навешивание обработчика на onload, если скрипт стоит до формы :

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('slap').addEventListener('click', say_hi);">
```

!!!

и как указано, заменить type на button или вставить preventDefault